# ¿Cómo puedo pasar de un cuadrado de asteriscos a un cuadrado de números?

Tags: java

Ejemplo de salida:

```
11111 
22222 
33333 
44444 
55555
```

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo pasar de un cuadrado de asteriscos a un cuadrado de números. Aquí les dejo el código que cree para el primer caso. Para el segundo caso no tengo ningún código ya que no sé como resolverlo. No pido que me lo resuelvan sino una explicación de cómo realizarlo.

Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Cuadro{
    public static void main(String...Args){
        Scanner lector=new Scanner(System.in);
        //Mandamos mensaje por pantalla para pedir la dimensión del cuadro
        System.out.print(" Tamannio del cuadrado: ");
        int tam=lector.nextInt();
        //Haemos un siclo para Hacer la impresión de los * en la
        //parte superior * * * * *
        for(int col=1; col <= tam; col++)
            System.out.print(" *");

        System.out.print("\n");

        for(int fila=2; fila < tam; fila++){
            System.out.print(" *");
            for(int col=2; col < tam; col++)
                System.out.print("  ");

            System.out.print(" * \n");
        }
        for(int col=1; col <= tam; col++)
            System.out.print(" *");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola jose manuel, no olvides formular tu pregunta en base a [ask] para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas la solución a tu pregunta, realiza el [tour]!, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacerlo con dos bucles for anidados. Te explico cómo funciona eso.

Cuando estas haciendo

```
for(int col=1; col <= tam; col++)
        System.out.print(" *");
```

Estas diciendo cuántas columnas tendrá tu cuadrado, es decir, en caso de que hayas introducido un 4, tendrás 4 columnas.

Si dentro de ese bucle haces otro, por cada columna harás una fila. Podrías escribirlo así:

```
for (int col=1; col<=tam; col++){
    for(int fila=col; fila<=col; fila++){
        System.out.println(col);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Siguiendo la traza del bucle, es decir, recorriendolo paso a paso para ver qué hace, vemos lo siguiente:

Al entrar en el bucle en la primera vuelta, entra en el segundo bucle, el de las filas. Por cada vuelta en el segundo bucle dibujará un asterisco, uno detrás de otro. Al terminar el segundo bucle hace un salto de línea, y así hasta terminar el resultado.

Pruebalo y dime si te funciona, pero creo que así debería ir.

Comment: Me funciona gracias. ¿Y como podría cambiarlo para hacerlo con números? En vez de con asteriscos con números.

Comment: Acabo de editarlo para con números. Si pones en el System.out.println con una variable, te la imprimirá. Si pones que esa variable sea la variable de las columnas, te pondrá 4 veces un 1, luego 4 veces un 2... etc

Comment: Muchas gracias.